# SQL Server 2008 & 2012 Licence Fees for a Single Developer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, licensing

What are the SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 licence fees for a single developer?

It's impossible to tell from the Microsoft website.

Comment: I remember I read in one book (SQL Server 2008 R2 Unleashed) that the developer's edition costs 50$ per developer. Can't say anything about 2012

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2012 RTM yet, so you cannot buy it.

Comment: @Oybek, does that licence allows deploying to a commercial server? It's not just for development & staging?

Comment: @FreshCode no, just development. If you want to use it in production you should "upgrade" to the target edition (Standard, Enterprise, workgroup, etc.)

Comment: You can get sql 2012 developer for less than $49. (I paid $32.35 at provantage.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/how-to-buy.aspx

Since SQL Server 2012 isn't out yet, prizing seems to follow.
Found something about 2012 here:

http://www.windowslifestyle.com/microsoft-reveals-sql-server-2012-licensing-pricing/

> The licensing costs retained the same, decreased or increased. Horwitz shared his views in an e-mail, where he laid out the changes in bullet points.
>
> - The price of the SQL Server CAL does go up, about 25%.
> - The per-server license for Standard Edition remains the same price as before.
> - The per-server license for BI server is the same price as the server license for SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise…though this isn’t an apples to apples comparison given the difference in SKU features.
> - The per-core price for SQL 2012 Standard and Enterprise edition is one quarter the price of per-proc licenses for equivalent editions of SQL 2008 R2. So effectively, if you have more than 4 cores per physical processor in the server, your licensing fee goes up.”

Comment: That's 14 pages without a single Dollar amount.

Comment: Click "Which edition" and select one and then the price will be listed!

Comment: Just FYI - that first page says Developer Edition is $37.00, but I've never seen it for less than $49. Microsoft's own store retails it for $49.95 : http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/productID.221634300/ I don't think you'll find them selling 2008 anymore but you may find it at other retailers.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition will be in the same ballpark as current versions (2005, 2008 and 2008 R2 were all $49 or $49.95 depending on where you like to buy software).